# Grails deleteAll() fails with hibernate exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to run a delete all on a domain class where I qualify one of the classes attribute values (both Member.submissionId and submission.id as long types).

Here's my code:

```
def memberCount = Member.where{ eq( "submissionId", submission.id ) }.deleteAll()
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: member near line 1, column 57 [DELETE my.domain.Member member WHERE (member.submissionId=?)]
```

Other deletes I have where I reference the submission object seem to work ok:

```
def subErrorCount = SubmissionError.where{ eq( "submission", submission ) }.deleteAll()
```

For this delete, the generated SQL is correct:

```
delete from submission_error where submission_id=?
```

The only difference I can see is that SubmissionError belongs to the parent Submission object, where Member has a soft link to the Submission via its submissionId attribute (it belongs to another object).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: also, am I correct in assuming that this delete method is not a cascade delete due to the SQL it generates? i.e. objects that belong to the selected Members will not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 'member' is a reserved word in HQL. I would suggest changing the domain model name if it's not much of a hassle.

Comment: That is quite a big risk/hassle I think. What other ways can I run this delete query? Ideally, with the cascade delete too.

Comment: not so pretty but it will work: Member.where{ eq( "submissionId", submission.id ) }.each { it.delete() }

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the badly generated HQL by writing the query as an HQL query yourself:

```
Member.executeUpdate("delete Member m where m.submissionId = :subId", [subId: submission.id])
```